# Updating List with AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, soap-api, list, ssjs

I am looking for a way to update a list using AMPscript by just pressing an update button and going through all of the checkboxes that I am pulling from Marketing Cloud. This is all for a custom profile center that I am building using the boilerplate that has been posted here before.

I am pulling all of the public lists using SSJS from Marketing Cloud. If the subscriber wants to subscribe to said one of these lists, they would then choose the checkbox and then press the update button. I am looking for a specific way to post it back to marketing cloud that they want to be added to that list.

This may also require SOAP API also, which I am very basic on, so I am looking to see if there are any ways to do it with AMPscript or even both combined.

If there is any need of clarification let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [Web Collect](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_email_studio_web_collect.htm&type=5)?

You should be able to do this via AMPScript if you choose to not use the HTML form or need to POST multiple times for a single user submit.  See below for sample AMPScript using [HTTPPOST2()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/httppost2.htm):

(This example is for the S1 instance. For other instances, replace s# with the instance you are on for "cl.s#.exct.net".)

`%%=HTTPPost2(CONCAT('http://cl.exct.net/subscribe.aspx?lst="', @lid, '"_HTML&eml=', @EmailAddress, '&mid=', @MemberID'), 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', @content, true, @status, @respBody, @addtlHeaderName, @addtlHeaderValue)=%%`

You will need to fill in the lid (List ID), EmailAddress and MemberID sections with the appropriate information.

You would then place the additional values you want to fill inside of the @addtlHeaderName and @addtlHeaderValue parameters. You technically could add them to the target URL as well if you desired, but this would be exposed similar to a GET.